# Check if a string has number greater than 1

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a method returning me a string that may contain numbers. I extract those numbers into a string with comma-separated value.

```
var stringOne = "Returned 12 string";
var extractNum = "1,2"
```

What I want now is to check this string against a regular expression that tests to see if the string has numbers greater than 1? I've tried few things but none seems to be working. Please suggest a way to accomplish it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to see for `extractNum` if it has numbers greater than 1? And what have you tried?

Comment: Just to make sure: You do mean "numbers", not "digits"? Should `"10"` match or not?

Comment: @TimPietzcker, yes the numbers.

Comment: `"Returned 12 string".match(/([1-9])/g)` will return null if there is no match. It will return array of matched numbers

Comment: Your last two comments are mutually exclusive. If `stringOne` contains `10`, then `extractNum` contains `1,0`, none of which are greater than 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to test if your extract String containt numbers greater than 1, you can try below code

```
function check() {
        var str = "1,1,1,1,2,1,1";
        var patt = new RegExp("[2-9]");
        return patt.test(str); // true
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var matched = "Returned 12 string".match(/[2-9]/g)

if (matched !== null) {
    alert(matched.join(','));
} else {
// No match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
var extractNum = "1,2";
var hasGreaterThan1 = extractNum.split(',').some(function(val) { return val > 1; })
```

See documentation for [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would parse the number and use the actual numerical operators provided by Javascript to do this.

If you *really* must do it through a regular expression, you could use something like so: `^[2-9]|\d{2,}$`. This will check that the number is either a single digit between 2 and 9 or else a digit made up from two or more numbers.

Answer (score 0):

"ok" will be true if any number is bigger than 1;

```
var stringOne = "Returned 12 string";
var extractNum = "1,2"
var ok = haveNrBiggerThan1(extractNum);

function haveNrBiggerThan1(str){
    var nums = str.split(",");
    for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i++){var n=parseInt(nums[i]); if(n>1){return true;}}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: damn you have beaten me by 20 secs :p

Answer (score 0):

Without using regular expression

```
extractNum.split(',').map(function(a){return parseInt(a)>1})
```